# Display website section page views in Data Studio pie chart - using Adobe Analytics data

Tags: analytics

I'm looking to display page views per website section in a pie chart in Data studio with data from Adobe Analytics.

So total page views for pages within each section to determine which area is getting most page views.

```
www.domain.co.uk/website-section-A 
www.domain.co.uk/website-section-B
www.domain.co.uk/website-section-C
www.domain.co.uk/website-section-D
```

is this achiveable?

Thanks
Jim

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I had tried using segments, but then came across this page which has enabled me to complete the task https://datarunsdeep.com.au/blog/custom-content-grouping-data-studio